# Script employing for loop truncates last letter of string

Tags: java

I programmed a script for swapping each letter in a sentence with A with the letter next to it.

For example, `ABRACADABRA` becomes `BARCADABARA`... However, there is a problem, that when I compile the script it truncates the final A, resulting in `BARCADABARA`. This results in any string, even those not ending with an A.

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {

        String word = "ABRACADABRA";
        String finalword = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length()-1; i++) {

            String wordsub = word.substring(i, i+1);
            String wordsub2 = word.substring(i+1, i+2);

            if(wordsub.equals("A") && !wordsub2.equals("A")){
                i++;
                finalword = finalword + wordsub2;
                finalword = finalword + wordsub;
            } else {
                finalword = finalword + wordsub;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(finalword);
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way concatenating strings in loop is a bad idea which can cause serious performance drawback for moreless long strings. Consider using `StringBuilder`.

Comment: This is for an AP COMPUTER SCIENCE practice... do you think `StringBuilder` is part of the set? I don't think so, but thank you. @TagirValeev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem is that you stop iterating through the string at the second to last character but in 3 of the possible 4 cases you only add the character at the current index, ignoring the character at the final index.

When `i` is at the second to last index:

```
ABRACADABRA
         ^
```

`wordsub` is `R`, `wordsub2` is `A`, but you hit the else and only add `wordsub` to the final string, then the loop terminates because `i` is no longer less than length - 1.

This actually produces the correct result in the case that the the second to last letter is an 'A' and the last letter isn't because under those conditions the if conditional is true and both letters are added to the final string.

I see two easy ways to fix this:

1. Iterate to the end of the string and add more logic to prevent wordsub2 from getting a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`
2. Define `wordsub2` outside the loop and add a flag that's set inside the loop to indicate if you need to add it to the end of `finalword`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that, it is not iterating over the all characters and ending 1 character early. You can fix this by simply iterating over all the characters and also putting an additional check of not reached to an end of string before retrieving next character. So your modified code becomes like this

```
String finalword = "";

for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {

    String wordsub = word.substring(i, i+1);

    if( (i+1) == word.length()){
        finalword = finalword + wordsub;
        break;
    }

    String wordsub2 = word.substring(i+1, i+2);
    if(wordsub.equals("A") && !wordsub2.equals("A")){
         i++;
         finalword = finalword + wordsub2;
         finalword = finalword + wordsub;
     } else {
         finalword = finalword + wordsub;
     }
}
```

As a side effect, I also found that there are too many String manipulations are happenning. You should avoid that as using too many String will eat up memory. You can check below code as an alternative.

```
char wordArr[] = word.toCharArray();
StringBuilder finalWord = new StringBuilder();
int wordLength = wordArr.length;

for(int i=0; i < wordLength; i++){

    if( (wordArr[i]=='A') && (i!=wordLength-1)){
        finalWord.append(wordArr[i+1]);
        finalWord.append(wordArr[i]);
        i++;
    }else{
        finalWord.append(wordArr[i]);
    }

}
System.out.println(finalWord.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Very well constructed!

Comment: I'm sorry if this sounds ignorant, but where was the revised portion of the code that addressed my problem? I'm just having trouble locating it...

Comment: @seanlevan, no not at all ignorant. My mistake, I just forgot to add the code. Edited my answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Update the else part as follows

```
else{
  finalword = finalword + wordsub;
  finalword = finalword + wordsub2;
}
```

The changes will be done as follows

```
ABRACADABRA
A B
BA
R A
A C
BARACA
A D
BARACADA
A B
BARACADABA
R A
-------------------BARACADABARA
```

Answer (score 0):

When I read, "I programmed a script for swapping each letter in a sentence with A with the letter next to it." I think that the letter "A" can be to the left or to the right of a letter.

You're if statement `if(wordsub.equals("A") && !wordsub2.equals("A"))` only checks if the letter "A" is on the left and not on the right.

So in your first iteration, you swapped AB to BA then moved to R.  Well R is next to A (RA), but the A is on the right side instead of the left which fails the if statement.  Add an `||` clause to your if statement to account for this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String word = "ABRACADABRA";
    String finalword = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length()-1; i++) {

        String wordsub = word.substring(i, i+1);
        String wordsub2 = word.substring(i+1, i+2);

        if((wordsub.equals("A") && !wordsub2.equals("A")) ||
           (!wordsub.equals("A") && wordsub2.equals("A"))) {
            i++;
            finalword = finalword + wordsub2;
            finalword = finalword + wordsub;
        } else {
            finalword = finalword + wordsub;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(finalword);
}
```

Results:

> BAARACADBAR